# How do you calibrate a proton-recoil scintillation fast neutron detector?

Tags: photons, radiation, neutrons, gamma-rays, particle-detectors

I have a proton recoil scintillator, but gamma sources like Cs-137, Co-60 don't seem to have linear calibration for the device. Are there other ways of calibrating this device? I'm trying to detect fast neutrons from a Cf-252 source.

Comment: With difficulty? Seriously, detectors based on scintillator generally have non-linear energy scales if you have to look at response over large ranges of energy deposition and recoil protons have a huge quenching factor (which changes rapidly with initial energy). To point you in the right direction (because I have never done this) you'll need a couple sources (or more) with strong and well defined neutron lines (google "neutron generator" for a start), and to go farther than that you'll probably want a Monte Carlo of the device.